SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine was selected
I'm trying to connect my windows machine with xampp, using php with PDO, to a server on the local network (Linux)
<?php

$dbname = "DBNAME";
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;port=PORT;dbname=" . $dbname, $user, $pass);
    echo "Conexão com o banco de dados realizada com sucesso";
} catch(PDOException $err) {
    echo "Erro ao conectar ao banco: ". $err->getMessage();
}
?>

This gives me an error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]No connections could be made because the target machine actively refused them
How to solve the problem?

Are you sure that's the exact error message? I can't find any other references to it when I google, my searches only return No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Yeah, as the image shows https://ibb.co/wRg35BQ

That's Portugese. I don't think you're translating it properly.

Please post the error as text so we can copy/paste.

When I paste "a maquina de destino as recusou ativamente" into translate.google.com I get "the target machine actively refused them". Look up the error message I posted, you'll find many answers that explain what causes it.

Put simply, it means there's no MySQL server running on the host/port you specified, or there's a firewall blocking you.

You are right, the correct translation is: No connections could be made because the target machine actively refused them

I made sure that there is a mysql server running, and that the ports and settings are correct, the server's firewall may be blocking me?

Is the MySQL server the same machine as the PHP? Try using localhost instead of a hostname and port.

No, they are different machines on the same network, I tested the PHP script on the same MYSQL machine and the connection was made, and the Linux firewall is inactive, in addition, the Linux server connects to other applications such as zabbix, which makes me leads me to think that it could be a configuration problem with my local php, in which I use XAMPP

If you try to connect to the server using the mysql CLI client, does it work?

I can't think of anything in the local PHP that could cause this error.

when performing "netstat -a" on the MySQL server
my connection is specified as
tcp6  0  444  zabbix:ssh  MY_IP:51498  ESTABLISHED
a 444 appears in the Send-Q column, is this a problem?

That's your SSH login session, it has nothing to do with MySQL.
